# How to assign Stripe customer IDS to existing Users in Pay Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I'm using the Rails pay gem, which when a user registers, assigns automatically a Stripe Customer ID to the User with the following method in the User model:

```
pay_customer default_payment_processor: :stripe
```

The problem is, I have old users which are already registered, and when trying to pay with an old account, theres is no stripe customer id so it gives an error.

**¿How can I automatically assign a Stripe customer ID to each User in my ddbb with the pay gem?**

I tried iterating each User like:

```
User.find_each do |user|
  unless user.payment_processor.present?
    user.set_payment_processor :stripe
    user.save
    puts "Created Stripe Customer ID for user: #{user.email}"
  end
end
```

This will assign a payment processor, but it won't create a Stripe Customer ID for the user.

Please, can someone help with this? I'm really stuck :(

**My logs**

```
3.0.0 :011 > u.set_payment_processor :stripe
  TRANSACTION (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Pay::Customer Update All (0.7ms)  UPDATE "pay_customers" SET "default" = $1 WHERE "pay_customers"."owner_id" = $2 AND "pay_customers"."owner_type" = $3  [["default", false], ["owner_id", 388], ["owner_type", "User"]]
  Pay::Customer Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "pay_customers".* FROM "pay_customers" WHERE "pay_customers"."owner_id" = $1 AND "pay_customers"."owner_type" = $2 AND "pay_customers"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "pay_customers"."processor" = $3 ORDER BY "pay_customers"."id" ASC LIMIT $4  [["owner_id", 388], ["owner_type", "User"], ["processor", "stripe"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Pay::Customer Exists? (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "pay_customers" WHERE "pay_customers"."processor_id" = $1 AND "pay_customers"."id" != $2 AND "pay_customers"."processor" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["processor_id", "cus_XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"], ["id", 1], ["processor", "stripe"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Pay::Customer Update (0.2ms)  UPDATE "pay_customers" SET "default" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "pay_customers"."id" = $3  [["default", true], ["updated_at", "2023-08-31 20:18:04.191958"], ["id", 1]]
  TRANSACTION (0.6ms)  COMMIT
  Pay::Customer Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "pay_customers".* FROM "pay_customers" WHERE "pay_customers"."owner_id" = $1 AND "pay_customers"."owner_type" = $2 AND "pay_customers"."default" = $3 AND "pay_customers"."deleted_at" IS NULL LIMIT $4  [["owner_id", 388], ["owner_type", "User"], ["default", true], ["LIMIT", 1]]
 => 
#<Pay::Customer:XXXXXXXXXXXXX
 id: 1,
 owner_type: "User",
 owner_id: 388,
 processor: "stripe",
 processor_id: "cus_XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
 default: true,
 data: {},
 deleted_at: nil,
 created_at: Mon, 24 Jul 2023 11:19:25.540934000 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Thu, 31 Aug 2023 20:18:04.191958000 UTC +00:00,
 payment_method_token: nil> 
3.0.0 :012 > u.payment_processor.customer
/Users/XXXXXX/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/pay-6.6.1/lib/pay/stripe/billable.rb:66:in `rescue in customer': No such customer: 'cus_XXXXXXXXXXXX' (Pay::Stripe::Error)
/Users/XXXXXXXX/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/stripe-8.5.0/lib/stripe/stripe_client.rb:722:in `handle_error_response': No such customer: 'cus_XXXXXXXXXXXXX' (Stripe::InvalidRequestError)
3.0.0 :013 >
```

Thanks

Comment: Based on the Pay gem's readme, it looks like `user.set_payment_processor :stripe` should create a Customer in Stripe. What do you see if you try to retrieve the associated Customer object that was created via `@user.payment_processor.customer`? If that is showing that a Customer is not being created, it may be worth flagging this as an issue in the pay gem repo.

Comment: I added my logs. I can see its updating the payment processor but It won't create a Stripe User.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting all of my existing Pay Customer records fixed this for me in development.